# Given a set of string segments, is there a way to calculate the hashCode so it equals the hashcode of the concated string?

Tags: java, hash

Consider:

```
String[] segments = {"asdf", "qwerty", "blahblah", "alongerstring", "w349fe3434"};
String fullString = "asdfqwertyblahblahalongerstringw349fe3434";
```

Is there an efficient way to combine the hashCode()s of each of element in segments in such a way that it equals the hashCode of fullString?

Obviously if I loop over every character in all the segments, I can come up with the same result as fullString.hashCode(), but that doesn't take advantage of the cached hashCodes in each of the segment string objects.  I would like to avoid looping over each character of each segment.  Also I can't cache the looped-over hashcode for segments, because sets of segments might be combined to create a full string.

So basically, I would like something that does this:

```
int segmentHash = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < segments.length; i++)
{
    segmentHash = combine(segmentHash, segments[i].hashCode());
}
assert(segmentHash == fullString.hashCode());
```

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, yes.

Looking how the `String`'s [hashCode is calculated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) (`s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`), you need to do the following:

1. for appending one segment: multiply the hash code of the initial segment by 31^L, where L is the length of the second segment, and add the hash code of the second segment
2. do the same iteratively for the rest of segments.

Edit:
Of course, you need to know additionally the lengths of the segments. Without this information the calculation is obviously impossible.

Comment: Oh wow, of course. :) Note that the ^ operator here is exponentiation, not XOR.

Comment: @Mark: yes, that's basically why it works. I wonder if the actual algorithm was chosen with exactly this purpose: to be able to calculate hash from hash for parts. (Maybe because some parts of different strings could be shared by compiler?)

Comment: I'm probably being bone-headed, but it doesn't seem to work for me:       int hash = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < segments.length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                hash = segments[0].hashCode();
            else
                hash = (int) Math.pow(31, segments[i].length()) *  hash + segments[i].hashCode();
        }  edit:  It seems to work up to 3 segments, but for 4 or more it doesn't.

Comment: It seems to work for String[] segments = {"asdf", "qwerty"}; but not for String[] segments = {"asdf", "qwerty123456"};   int is overflowing or something.

Comment: @deliciousirony: I guess, `Math.pow` is overflowing. You should just multiply 31 by itself L times instead of using `pow`.

Comment: or using squared exponentiation `int fac=1,t=31,l=segments[i].length();while(l!=0){fac*=(l&1==1)?t:1;t*=t;l/=2;}`

Comment: @ratchet freak: yes, your code is basically logarithmic on `l`.

Comment: works also if "(int) Math.pow(31, segments[i].length())" in deliciousirony's version of the code is replaced with "new BigInteger("31").pow(segments[i].length()).intValue()"

Comment: @A.J. bigInt is overkill here (besides `BigInteger.valueOf(31).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(segments[i].length()),BigInteger.valueOf(1L<<32)).intValue()` maintains the mod 2^32 arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

String has a well defined [hashcode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)

it is [calculated](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode) as

```
int off = offset;
char val[] = value;
int len = count;
for (int i = 0; i <  len; i++) {
    h = 31*h + val[off++];
}
hash = h;
```

(with offset the start of the string and count the length of the string

so if you want to do it yourself:

```
int hash=0;
for(String str;segments){
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        hash=hash*31+str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

edit: or working from vlads suggestion

```
int hash = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) { 
    int fac=1,t=31,l=segments[i].length();
    while(l!=0){
        fac*=(l&1==1)?t:1;
        t*=t;
        l/=2;
    }
    hash = fac * hash + segments[i].hashCode(); 
}
```

Comment: No, this won't work. The OP wants the hash to be calculated from the _hashes_ of parts, not from the parts themselves!